# Сложное условие в Excel (множественное условие если)

Tags: функции, excel, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть основная таблица: столбцы A и B,в столбце B стоят данные, например 001230, 001273, 001479, 000720,  нужно в соответствии с таблицей на скрине записать в столбец A соответствующее значение (A, B, ..., M) из диапазона От и До(включительно) (если в столбце До ничего не стоит, значит просто равно столбцу От).
Например, 
F 001273 
A 001479
K 000720

Как это можно реализовать при помощи функции Если? (офис урезанный, функций ВПР, ЕСЛИМН, УСЛОВИЕ нет, переустановить офис на нормальный возможности тоже нет)

Comment: Не встречал такого, чтобы *ЕСЛИ* была, а *ВПР* отсутствовала... Вопрос похож на "а можно ли только с ЕСЛИ"? Можно, если "урезанный офис" допускает не менее 64 вложений. Но пока задача непонятна. === Записать в столбец А... Откуда брать эти буквы? Вернее, как понять, к какому диапазону какая буква относится? === Какие функции еще есть, кроме ЕСЛИ? Например, ВЫБОР? === Макросом, видимо, тоже нельзя?

Comment: условие задачи тоже довольно урезано, может все-таки есть возможность объяснить что в итоге нужно получить?

Comment: @vikttur Функция ВЫБОР есть, диапазон букв дан на скрине. А смысл задачи таков: дан excel файл, в котором записаны индексы в столбце B, нужно в соответствии со скрином присвоить каждому индексу в файле букву в столбец А. Стоит офис професиональный плюс 2016.

Comment: @slippyk Задача такова: дан excel файл, в котором записаны только индексы в столбце B, нужно в соответствии со скрином в посте(диапазоны) присвоить каждому индексу в файле букву в столбец А.

Comment: @Ольга, это все понятно и три раза описывать одно и то же не нужно. Вопрос был: какая логика присвоения букв? Почему, например,  в третьей строке А, в 15-й - Н,  в 7-й  - Е?

Comment: @vikttur Логики конкретной нет, это на подобии почтовых индексов по районам, когда у каждого района индексы в нескольких диапазонах.

Comment: @Ольга: *у каждого района индексы в нескольких диапазонах* - в любом случае от чего-то нужно отталкиваться. Или какая-то логика,  или таблица соответствий *диапазон/буква* ==== Какой размер диапазона для одной буквы? Диапазоны разные по величине или одинаковые? Диапазоны могут перекрывать друг друга? Количество возможных диапазонов? Наименьшее и наибольшее значения в столбце В?

Comment: @vikttur Диапазон разный, перекрывать друг друга не будут, таблица соответствий такова:  A: 000001-000034, 000901-000910, 001479,000520, 000580, 000582-000584, 000586-000588, 000591, 000593, 000594;
B: 001021-001066;
C: 001100-001161;
D: 001200-001253;
E 001260-001296, 001370-001391, 000540-000566, 
F 01301-001355
G: 001405-001478, 001480-000490,000900-000912;
H: 000501-000519, 000521-000535, 000600-000627;
J: 000630-000695;
K: 000700-000726, 000800-000832;
L: 000730-000792;
M: 000850-000899.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> когда офис урезанный, функций ВПР, ЕСЛИМН, УСЛОВИЕ нет

Сложно что-либо советовать, т.к. непоятно, что есть...

Остается только вариант с перебором - вложенные функции *ЕСЛИ*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(--B2>=1;--B2<=34);И(--B2>=901;--B2<=910);--B2={520;580;582;583;584;586;587;588;591;593;594;1479});"A";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=1021;--B2<=1066);"B";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=1100;--B2<=1161);"C";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=1200;--B2<=1253);"D";
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(--B2>=540;--B2<=566);И(--B2>=1260;--B2<=1296);И(--B2>=1370;--B2<=1391));"E";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=1301;--B2<=1355);"F";
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(--B2>=900;--B2<=912);И(--B2>=1405;--B2<=1478);И(--B2>=1480;--B2<=149));"G";
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(--B2>=501;--B2<=519);И(--B2>=521;--B2<=535);И(--B2>=600;--B2<=627));"H";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=630;--B2<=695);"J";
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(--B2>=700;--B2<=726);И(--B2>=800;--B2<=832));"K";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=730;--B2<=732);"L";
ЕСЛИ(И(--B2>=850;--B2<=899);"M";
"нет"))))))))))))
```

Для удобства редактирования условия для каждой буквы разнесены по строкам.

Двойное отрицание преобразует текстовую запись числа в число.

Разные диапазоны для одной буквы объединяются по условию *ИЛИ*, диапазон значений проверяется условием *И*. Для упрощения константы записаны в массиве констант (массив в фигурных скобках {}).